# Pretty URL with htaccess on one param encoded URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

this is the link that would like to convert from:

`http://localhost/home/comment.php?id=k76t%2BPM1AYUlz%2Bz7sY%2BHg7F5p`

into this:

`http://localhost/home/comment/id/k76t%2BPM1AYUlz%2Bz7sY%2BHg7F5p`

also note that this is in the `href` tag, so when user click it should show the clean version, however, to test it, i type the pretty version manually in http address bar, it still wouldn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^home/comment/id/^(.+)/(.+)/?$ home/comment.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] #attempt 1

RewriteRule ^home/comment/id/(.*)$ home/comment.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] #attempt 2

RewriteRule ^home/comment/id/([-A-Za-z0-9%]+)$ home/comment.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] #attempt 3
```

Comment: `RewriteRule home/comment/id/(.*)$ home/comment.php [QSA, L]`. You will have the whole request string in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` available in comment.php. Explode as you need.

Comment: I would recommend you to read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application) instead of adding a bunch of different rules in your htaccess. It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. And since you only need one single rule (that redirects all requests to non-existing files to index.php), it's easier to move it between web servers (not all use htaccess).

Comment: RewriteRule ^home/comment/id/(.*) home/comment.php?id=$1